# During the page, How I can show screenshot to avoid SPEED INDEX error?

Tags: performance, indexing, loading

My site URL : https://tenguren.com/

Problem: It is showing "Speed Index Error!" every time and the message is "Chrome didn't collect any screenshots during the page load...". Actually, I couldn't understand what I should do. At the time of loading, it is showing loading animation by "loading container" on html/CSS.